# Error running grails application

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have a grails application in 1.3.7 but on running the application it shows following message:

| 'Application expects grails version [1.3.7], but GRAILS_HOME is version [2.1.0] - use the correct Grails version or run 'grails upgrade' if this Grails version is newer than the version your application expects'.

If i type ${GRAILS_HOME} it is pointing to 1.3.7,It means grails home is already pointing to 1.3.7 .

I am also using 2.0.1 for other applications.

Any suggestions ?????

Answer (score 1):

Your PATH environment variable is most likely picking up grails 2.1.0.  If you are on unix type `which grails` to find out which grails dir is in your path.

Answer (score 1):

I think so, you have two grails versions, but one or the two versions is in system path, and was you run, is running a version different of the GRAILS_HOME, you should have only one in path and in GRAILS_HOME, and shold has the same version.